# Page view controller attached to multiple scroll view

Tags: dart, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

i have an issue with page view, it's working fine for first initialization (i mean when open the screen that contain page view from "Screen A" then go to open the "pageView screen" from other screen called "Screen B") in second time getting this issue

i think this issue happen because the controller re-intialiazed again, but i dispose the controller and make it equal to null when dispose screen

```
ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart':
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_controller.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 109 pos 12: '_positions.length == 1'
```

Using provider to handle change in tabBar and Page View, the below code of provider class

```
class PageViewProvider extends BaseViewModel {
  // Tabs Controller
  int selectedTapIndex = 0;
  PageController? pageViewController;
  initPageIndex(int index) {
    if (pageViewController != null) {
      pageViewController = null;
    }
    print('init index $index');
    selectedTapIndex = index;
    pageViewController = PageController(initialPage: index, keepPage: false);
  }

  void changeSelectedTapIndex(int index) {
    selectedTapIndex = index;
    setState(ViewState.Idle);
  }

  void changePageView(int index) {
    pageViewController!.jumpToPage(index);
  }
}
```

this the tabed item widget with onTap Function to change index of TabBar

```
Consumer<PageViewProvider>(
    builder: (context, pageViewProvider, _) => Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Icon(
                iconData,
                color:
                    pageViewProvider.selectedTapIndex == selectedIndex
                        ? purpleColor
                        : grey500,
              ),
              normal14Text(
                title,
                color:
                    pageViewProvider.selectedTapIndex == selectedIndex
                        ? purpleColor
                        : grey500,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ).onTap(() {
          pageViewProvider.changeSelectedTapIndex(selectedIndex!);
          pageViewProvider.changePageView(selectedIndex!);
        }));
```

at least, this is the pageView body

```
Consumer<PageViewProvider>(
    builder: (context, pageViewProvider, _) => PageView(
      controller: pageViewProvider.pageViewController,
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        pageViewProvider.changeSelectedTapIndex(index);
      },
      pageSnapping: true,
      children: [
        LeadProfileContent(),
        LeadProfileTimeLine(),
        LeadProfileCases(),
        LeadProfileDeals(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved. The issue here was with the Consumer above the page view body. Just removed it, and then accessed the pageViewController like this:

```
context.read<PageViewProvider>.pageViewController
```